# What is the best way to access data by two computers?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, connection

Currently I have a single PC with all the data located in the internal Hard Drive. This PC is constantly busy optimizing data on the hard drive. Most the files on the internal Hard Drive are about 5 MB which are access about 10 times in a second and a single 2GB file is is accessed about once in 1 minute. Also, fresh data is added daily to this internal drive using internet connection.

Now, I want to add second PC to my setup which will also do optimizations on the said data. Some of the options available are :

1. Connect both PCs directly via lan cable or through router and map drive of first computer to another. I think this will be slow but error proof.
2. Make redundant copy of data and keep maintaining the same each day. This might be prone to error.
3. Add a NAS and let both computers read and write from common location and optimize on the same.

Please suggest me any other alternatives or help me choose what might work best for my scenario.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/166424/how-to-sync-files-between-computers-without-storing-them-in-the-cloud/

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 do you suggest to go with second option and keep redundant copy of data?

Comment: yeah bro it can be considered as one of the options

Comment: You need to indicate what kind of software is in use. If it implements locking both computers will stalemate and no data will be edited.

Comment: To me, it sounds like your setup is broken by design. But a lot of information is missing before anybody would be able to make a resonable suggestion. E.g. what kind of "optimisation" is performed on the data.

Comment: we can assume that all data is read only and optimization results are stored separately. I can make sure that no new data is overwritten. I am only concerned about how best to access the data as read-only.

Comment: Also, daily updates to data are new files only from a single computer. No old files are edited.